# Strength of faith in coming of the Messiah

Tags: messiah, wedding, faith-bitachon-emunah

I recall hearing long ago that some Jews send out wedding invitations as follows: "The wedding will be in Jerusalem at this place and time.  If, heaven forbid, the Messiah has not come by that time, the wedding will be in New York at this hotel.".

Is this true and documented, and if so, do they make arrangements for a wedding in Jerusalem?

Comment: I believe this originated with R’ Levi Yitzchak of Barditchev, obviously replacing New York with Barditchev in His invitations. I haven’t heard of this being done nowadays, so I can’t fully answer the question. Be careful if doing this yourself; according to Rav Zilberstein, if you use this expression in the sense of “Mashiach’s never going to come, so we’re going to have it in New York,” it’s tantamount to Kefirah. (If you mean it in the literal sense of the phrase, there’s no issue, though; cf. Sotah 48b, from Ezra 2:63.)

Comment: You mean that, if you do it, you HAVE to make arrangements in both Jerusalem and NY?

Comment: I didn’t say that, but I didn’t say otherwise, either. My gut reaction would be that if one says that it will be in Yerushalayim if Mashiach comes but doesn’t make arrangements (assuming that he is able to do so), it belies his claim that he means it seriously, and therefore goes against Rav Zilberstein’s psak. That said, perhaps it’s against Emunas Mashiach if one doesn’t make arrangements in Yerushalayim even if he *doesn’t* add this to the invitations.